# Conditional Page Break in RML

Tags: reporting, odoo, page-break, rml, page-break-inside

I am using rml as reporting language for openerp7. In there i would require to put a page break after a text.

**My Code is below**

```
   <!-- Here i am printing a table which consumes half of the page -->
   <b> This is the first page Text. After this all should come in the second page </b>

   <blockTable style="Table4">
   <condPageBreak height="8cm"/> <!--This doesn't work. even if i give any value to the height attribute -->
      <tr>
        <td>
          <para style="P26"> Text as a paragraph   </para>
        </td>
     </tr>
    </blockTable>
```

Kindly Clarify me. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

This works fine for me.

```
  <!-- Here i am printing a table which consumes half of the page -->
  <b> This is the first page Text. After this all should come in the second page </b>

<condPageBreak height="9cm"/>
  <blockTable style="Table4">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <para style="P26"> Text as a paragraph   </para>
    </td>
 </tr>
</blockTable>
```

It was a mistake to give it as less.